# ASP.NET Core 3.1.1 MVC + angular : how should I get all recipes from user(id)?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-mvc

I'm learning ASP.NET MVC, currently working on single page app in ASP.NET Core 3.1.1 with API's

I have `User.cs` which has collection of his `Recipes`.

In my `User` class I have a property:

```
public ICollection<Recipe> Recipes {get; set;}
```

`Recipe.cs` has properties

```
public class Recipe
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Ingredients { get; set; }
    public int PreparationTime { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RecipePhoto> RecipePhotos {get; set;}
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

I have 2 controllers, `RecipesController` and `UserController`, in which I can do things like `GetUser(id)`, `GetUsers()`, `GetRecipe(id)`, `GetRecipes()`.

This example shown here is how I get a single user and all users in my controller:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IRecipesRepository _repository;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public UsersController(IRecipesRepository repository, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet] 
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers ()
    {
        var users = await _repository.GetUsers();

        var usersToReturn = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<UserForListDto>>(users);

        return Ok(usersToReturn);
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")] 
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser (int id)
    {
        var user = await _repository.GetUser(id);

        var userToReturn = _mapper.Map<UserForDetailDto>(user);

        return Ok(userToReturn);
    }
```

And I would like to get all the user's recipes as well.

I should be something like `localhost:4200/users/1/recipes`

I'm not sure that the way i'm thinking is good.

Maybe i should try GetRecipes from Recipe class in which is Located UserId ?

I should recive List insead of single user

Comment: why don't you try: `[Route("users/{id}/recipes")]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to amend your controller to:

```
[HttpGet("{id}/{withRecipe?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser (int id, bool withRecipe = false)
```

This will match:
/users/1
and also 
/users/1/true

Then add a new repository method e.g:

```
GetUserWithRecipe(id)
{
return await _context.Users
    .Include(u => u.Recipes)
    .ThenInclude(r => r.RecipePhotos)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(r => r.Id == id);
}
```

And back in your controller, do:

```
var user = withRecipe? _repository.GetUserWithRecipe(id) : _repository.GetUser(id);
```

Not sure how to use the await keyword with that but you could amend to an 'if' statment instead.

This could be made more efficient by re-using the same repository method / queries instead of creating a separate method but it gives the idea.

Alternative is to create another controller method with:

```
[HttpGet("{id}/recipes")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser (int id)
```

Which directly calls the repository method with the recipe include.

This gives you the url as you asked for.

Comment: I can't use this method at my repository like this. _yourContext.Users.Include(u => u.Recipes); 
321/5000
The element "IIncludableQueryable <User, ICollection <Recipe>>" does not contain the definition "GetAwaiter" and the available method of the extension "GetAwaiter" was not found, which takes the first argument of the type "IIncludableQueryable <User, ICollection <Recipe>>" (is there a missing directive or references to the kit?). [RecipesApp.API]

Comment: Try _yourContext.Users.Include(u => u.Recipes).SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);